# Count of all occurrences on all rows

Tags: sql, count

I need to complete an overall count of occurrences of one column and all rows.

As an example of data:

[image]

How many times the place has occurred.

I've done this so far which counts the years but how do I then do a count on that count

```
SELECT year,count(year)
from
countries group by place-name
```

So how do I now count my places by the year counts? For example Birkenhead would equal 7

Comment: In the column `YEAR`, are all years stored as a comma-separated string?

Comment: Please mention your dbms and expected result from the sample data.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results, including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select DISTINCT(place-name), count(*) 
from 
countries group by place-name
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try! :-)

Comment: In the column YEAR, are all years stored as a comma-separated string? – The Impaler 9 mins ago - Yes

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results, including a Minimal, Reproducible Example and not as images – Stu 1 min ago   -   I would like to see the following:     PLACE-NAME - OCCURRENCES COUNT

Comment: Please mention your dbms and expected result from the sample data. – Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur 4 mins ago   - they will mainly be Graph DBs